# Ubuntu 18.04 Screen Share Networks only wifi show up

Tags: networking, vino

I have a HTPC with Ubuntu 18.04. This PC have two Networks:

- wifi with DNS and Gateway (Internet)
- Ethernet without DNS or Gateway

I open Settings -> Sharing -> Screen Sharing. In the "Networs Field" i can only see my wifi SSID. Is this a Bug?

The other thing is. I can't start vino-preferences neither.